# CakePHP retrieving incorrect ID

Tags: php, mysql, database, cakephp

I currently have a running CakePHP application version 1.3.11. I am using this find method to retrieve data from my database.

```
$data = $this->Data->find('all', array('conditions' => array('Table.expired' => '0', 'Table.deleted' => '0'), 'order' => 'Table.date ASC', 'limit' => 20));
```

The problem is this method is returning 3 ids all the same for each row. One is the primary key and the others are a foreign key and that foreign tables id (The two foreign ones should be the same). The ids found in the data variable belong to foreign key.
For example this should be the result:

```
table1 =
   id = 51
   sites_id = 67
sites =
   id = 67
```

but it is currently doing this:

```
table1 =
   id = 67
   sites_id = 67
sites =
   id = 67
```

Any ideas would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

try printing the SQL string generated, i am very sure is something related with `"select table.id as id"`